# Troubles with routing Symfony3 (KernelRequest)

Tags: php, routes, kernel, symfony

I have some troubles with the framework symfony. I use KernelRequest to manage with my routes.
In a controller, I have the right route name and the right params; but in another controller (which is exactly the same, just the page changes) the route generates params like http, https, scheme, etc (see below).

Candidate.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\AppBundle;
use AppBundle\Entity\CandidateAction;
use AppBundle\Entity\CandidateNotice;
use AppBundle\Entity\CandidateSchool;
use AppBundle\Entity\CandidateSkill;
use AppBundle\Entity\Document;
use AppBundle\Entity\ListElement;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use AppBundle\Entity\Candidate;
use AppBundle\Form\CandidateType;
use AppBundle\Utils\EnumRight;
use AppBundle\Utils\EventCalendar;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;
use MBence\OpenTBSBundle\OpenTBSBundle;

/**
 * Candidat controller.
 *
 * @Route("/candidate")
 */
class CandidateController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Candidat entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="candidate_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->set('tabActive', 'personalData');
        $userHistory = $session->get("userContext")->getUserHistory();
        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        if ($session->get("userContext")->hasPermission($user, EnumRight::candidate, EnumRight::candidate_show_list)) {
            return $this->render('AppBundle:candidate:index.html.twig', array());
        } else {
            $this->get("session")->getFlashBag()->add('danger', $this->get('translator')->trans('rights.forbidden'));
            $userHistory->popFromHistory();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($userHistory->getPreviousRoute()['name'], $userHistory->getPreviousRoute()['params']));
        }
    }
}
```

tender.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\AppBundle;
use AppBundle\Entity\Document;
use AppBundle\Entity\ListElement;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use AppBundle\Entity\Tender;
use AppBundle\Form\TenderType;
use AppBundle\Utils\EnumRight;
use AppBundle\Utils\EventCalendar;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;
use MBence\OpenTBSBundle\OpenTBSBundle;



/**
 * Tender controller.
 *
 * @Route("/tender")
 */
class TenderController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Tender entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="tender_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->set('tabActive', 'personalData');
        $userHistory = $session->get("userContext")->getUserHistory();
        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        if ($session->get("userContext")->hasPermission($user, EnumRight::tender, EnumRight::tender_show_list)) {
            return $this->render('AppBundle:tender:index.html.twig', array());
        } else {
            $this->get("session")->getFlashBag()->add('danger', $this->get('translator')->trans('rights.forbidden'));
            $userHistory->popFromHistory();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($userHistory->getPreviousRoute()['name'], $userHistory->getPreviousRoute()['params']));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's exactly the same function in two different controllers.

The route for the first one : (with a dump in my html view)

```
"name" => "candidate_index"
"params" => []
```

The route for the second one :

```
"name" => "tender_index"
    "params" => array:5 [▼
      "path" => "/tender/"
      "permanent" => true
      "scheme" => null
      "httpPort" => 80
      "httpsPort" => 443
    ]
```

Here is the result of this command : php/bin console debug:router for both tender and candidate:

```
  $ php bin/console debug:router tender_index
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                   |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | tender_index                                            |
| Path         | /tender/                                                |
| Path Regex   | #^/tender/$#s                                           |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |
| Method       | GET                                                     |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                               |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: AppBundle:Tender:index                     |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
 $ php bin/console debug:router candidate_index
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                   |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | candidate_index                                         |
| Path         | /candidate/                                             |
| Path Regex   | #^/candidate/$#s                                        |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |
| Method       | GET                                                     |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                               |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: AppBundle:Candidate:index                  |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT : 
I've found the difference in the log file. 
This controller is called :

```
[2016-08-26 10:47:52] request.INFO: Matched route "tender_index". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction","path":"/tender/","permanent":true,"scheme":null,"httpPort":80,"httpsPort":443,"_route":"tender_index"},"request_uri":"http://capfivm403.capfigroup.domain.com/~mlerouzic/weberp.dev/web/app_dev.php/tender"} []
```

instead of :

```
[2016-08-26 10:52:56] request.INFO: Matched route "tender_index". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\TenderController::indexAction","_route":"tender_index"},"request_uri":"http://capfivm403.capfigroup.domain.com/~mlerouzic/weberp.dev/web/app_dev.php/tender/?httpPort=80&httpsPort=443&path=%2Ftender%2F&permanent=1"} []
```

Comment: check your routes [with the console commands](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/debug.html) instead of dumping them, all thos extra parameters you dump probably don't matter in the view.

Comment: You can see the result of this command in my post (I edited it). I still don't understand the difference and from where come theses parameters. Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten the name of the main route in my Tender Controller and ... it works... I don't really know why. Maybe a bug in the framework after a composer update in my console.